# Vue directive - passing in string

Tags: string, vue.js, vuejs2, custom-directive

I have the following custom directive in vue

```
<h1 v-role="'admin'">Your Dashboard</h1>
```

It works fine but would be cleaner without the single quotes. Is this possible?

```
  <h1 v-role="admin">Your Dashboard</h1>
```

Comment: Is admin a model? If so bind it `<h1 :v-role="admin">Your Dashboard</h1>`

Comment: it's not.  I think i have to live with it

Comment: You could think of using constants and then go like `<h1 v-role="ROLES.ADMIN"> Your Dashboard</h1>`. However this is question of preference.

Comment: @DF Thanks - is an interesting idea, don't know if I like it any more than strings.

Comment: in vuejs 2.*, you can define your custom directive to use `binding.expression` instead of `binding.value`. Hope it helps.

Comment: @SasanFarrokh it works, but vue throws and error "Property or method 'X' is not defined on the instace but referenced during render."